# Getting zero results in web scraping using XPath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am using the below two functions to scrape a page for getting download link for a song. The function`get_song_details` scrapes a link and finds song title & album and the function `get_download_url` scrapes another link to find the link for the song title which is passed as argument.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import time

def get_song_details(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    # retrieve song title from page
    song = tree.xpath('//font[@class="general"]/b[2]/text()')
    if song:
        song = song[0].strip()
    else:
        raise ValueError("Song Title: Webpage structure has changed.")
    song = song.split("-")[0] if song.find("-") else song

    # retrieve album name from link
    tokens = link.split("/")
    album = tokens[5] if len(tokens) > 6 else None

    song_details = {
        "title": song,
        "album": album,
    }

    return song_details


def get_download_url(song_details):
    title = song_details["title"]
    album = song_details["album"]

    url = "http://www.songspk.site/indian/anjaana_anjaani_2010.html"
    print song_details, url
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    download_url = tree.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "{0}")]/@href'.format(title))

    return download_url
```

The following code when executed works great. It prints `['http://www.songspk.link/link1/song1.php?songid=7753', 'http://www.songspk.link/link1/song1.php?songid=7759']` -

```
song_details = {
    "title": "Aas Paas Khuda",
    "album": "Anjaana Anjaani"
}
print get_download_url(song_details)
```

But, when I execute the following code snippet, I get an empty list even though the `song_details` dictionary has the same content as in the above hard-coded snippet.

```
song_details = get_song_details("http://www.glamsham.com/music/lyrics/anjaana-anjaani/aas-pass-khuda/1368/3089.htm")
print get_download_url(song_details)
```

I am not able to understand that the parameter `song_details` has the same title as in the above code snippet but even though it doesn't work.

Comment: Xpath is bad choice, you'd need to keep updating your code every time there is little change in website. Try CSS selectors https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraping-app/gpolcofcjjiooogejfbaamdgmgfehgff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a typo on one of the pages. Notice that you get the song title as `Aas Pass Khuda`, but on the `Songs.PK` page there is only `Aas Paas Khuda`. `Pass` vs `Paas`.

Comment: Actually, I see `Aas Paas Khuda` on the link `http://www.songspk.link/indian/anjaana_anjaani_2010.html` which I am trying to parse.

Comment: I am making some mistake (I don't know what) in the `get_song_details` function because the song title is generated in that function. I think so because when I hard code the same value, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @GautamMishra please reread the answer - the extracted from `glamsham.com` song is called "Aas Pass Khuda", but on `songspk` there is only "Aas Paas Khuda".

Comment: I realized the typo now. Thanks a lot for correcting this.